# IE9 bug with increased font-size of css content

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9

I have found a bug in IE9 but googling for it hasn't helped finding any solution yet.

The following works fine in FF 3 + 4, Chrome, Opera and even IE8, but not in IE9.

The HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
    <p class="inner">Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
div p {
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
div p:after {
    content: " sit amet";
}

div p:after {
    font-size: 1.3em;
}
div.outer p:after,
div p.inner:after {
    font-size: 3em;
}
```

The "sit amet" is **huge** in IE9, as it seems to multiply the font-size again and again. It's not possible to overwrite it with "!important" or other means of increasing the specificity (as e.g. the "div.outer" should already do it). It even seems that it gets **multiplied within the same declaration**, i.e. `div.outer p:after, div p.inner:after` won't multiply by 3, but by 9!

(Please note that the "inner" and "outer" classes are not necessary here. The same happens by declaring `div p {}` again and again. But it makes only sense with classes as a real-world example.)

Here is a test page: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4667354/temp/ie9-bug.html

Is there any solution?

**Edit:**

To clarify two misunderstandings:

1. The bug is **not** the usual behaviour that child elements multiply the font-size of its parent when `em` are used. The bug is that **font-sizes in generated content cannot be overwritten** and will multiply anyway when trying to. I.e. setting the font-size in `div p:after` once works, but **setting it again multiplies instead of overwrites it**.
2. To better see what the problem is (in case you don't have IE9 at hand), here are two screenshots of the test page: [in IE8 and any other modern browser](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4667354/temp/ie9-bug_ie8.png) and [in IE9](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4667354/temp/ie9-bug_ie9.png).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could try using `rem` instead of `em`, [IE9 supports it](http://caniuse.com/rem), then your sizes will then be relative to the base font size instead of multiplying together.  [Here's a good explanation](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/font-size-with-rem).

I would guess the difference here is that IE9 is treating the generated content as a child element while the other browsers aren't, hence the multiplication.

Comment: Wow, I haven't heard of `rem` yet. This definitely fixes it! :)
If IE9 really treats the generated content as a child element, does it mean that its DOM is (at least partly) broken (again)?

Comment: @selfthinker It might be - I've not checked up exactly how it's supposed to work, if you asked on [www-style](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/) you would get a definitive answer.

Comment: Just for the record: This doesn't fix the real issue, but is a good enough workaround. If the parent font-size should be adjustable, so that every child should automatically grow to the same proportion, this solution does not work. I.e. whenever the parent font-size is increased or decreased, the child with a `rem` value keeps its (wrong) font-size.

Comment: Actually, in IE generated content inherits font-size from itself, not the parent element.
This causes recursive font-size calculations, with results spinning out of control.
It's amazing that Microsoft has left this unfixed for three whole releases (9-11)

Answer (score 3):

This ***might*** have something to do with the difference between the parsed DOM trees from IE8 to IE9.

**Internet Explorer 8:**

- `<html>`

  - `<head>`
  - `<body>`

    - `<div class="outer">`

      - `<p class="inner">`

        - *Text - Lorem ipsum dolar*

**Internet Explorer 9:**

- `<html>`

  - `<head>`
  - `<body>`

    - *Text - Empty Text Node*
    - `<div class="outer">`

      - *Text - Empty Text Node*
      - `<p class="inner">`

        - *Text - Lorem ipsum dolar*
      - *Text - Empty Text Node*
    - *Text - Empty Text Node*

### Bonus Reading

- [Interoperable HTML Parsing in IE9](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/09/13/interoperable-html-parsing-in-ie9.aspx)

Comment: Hmm, good point. But that would mean that removing the whitespace would fix it, which it doesn't. When I remove the whitespace, it looks like the IE8 example (i.e. without the "Text - Empty Text Node" in between) and the bug is still present.

Comment: this typoe of anwsers are the best

Answer (score 3):

There is a work-around that allows font-sizes to be relative (`em` or `%`): add another class with the pseudo-element `font-size` reducing the size.

I've put together a [fiddle showing the workaround](http://jsfiddle.net/Skateside/heydh609/) but the basic code is below:

```
<p class="one">Test (1.25em = 20px)</p>
<p class="one two">Test (2em = 32px but 2.5em = 40px in IE)</p>
<p class="one one-ie two">Test (2em = 32px)</p>
```

The styles then look like this:

```
body {
    font-size: 16px;
}

.one::before {
    content:      "::before";
    font-family:  monospace;
    font-size:    1.25em;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.one-ie::before {
    font-size: 0.8em;
}

.two::before {
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

Most browsers will override the `.one-ie::before` selector with `.two::before` and IE's compounding will essentially negate the previous `font-size`. If IE fix the bug and allow pseudo-element styles to override rather than compound, the hack gets overridden like every other browser.

Comment: Love that hack! Made another jsfiddle that I find easier to comprehend, but that might just be me :) http://jsfiddle.net/74n060sf/1/

Comment: Yeah - I should have explained, `.one-ie` `font-size` is 1 / `.one` `font-size` (thus 1 / 1.25 = 0.8)

Answer (score 0):

I see the test page "sit amet" as huge in Firefox 4.0.1. Are you sure this is IE only and not actual spec'd behavior?

edit: and safari too. I'm on a Mac. I don't think this is an IE bug.

Comment: No, the "sit amet" is supposed to be big everywhere (i.e. 3em), but in IE9 it is much, much bigger (i.e. **11.7em**!). Please take a look in IE9 as well and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: I just added two screenshots to the question to clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen similar in other versions of IE using ems too. Try setting

```
HTML {
    font-size: 100%;
}
```

Should fix it!

Comment: No, the point is that font-sizes in *generated content cannot be overwritten*. That's the bug. If you cannot overwrite it, a `font-size: 100%` can't help as well.