# Internet Explorer strange font-size behaviour with :after and :after::hover pseudo classes

Tags: internet-explorer, font-size, pseudo-element

Today I found an internet explorer bug that left me confused. Apparently internet explorer doubles(?) the font size of an :after class if the font-size is set on both the :after and :hover::after.

I've set up a quick demo, and came up with a workaround that I don't like since it won't work if you want to display content in both :after and :hover::after states. Does anyone have any idea what could cause this behaviour and how to fix it properly?

http://jsfiddle.net/q15Lw90d/7/

```
:hover{} /* Fixes pseudo-element animation on :hover
            for Internet Explorer 10 */

.workaround::after {
    content: "";
    font-size:2em;
}

.workaround:hover::after {
    color:green;
    content:", internet explorer";
}

.iebug::after {
    content: "";
    font-size:2em;
}

.iebug:hover::after {
    color:green;
    font-size:2em;
    content:", internet explorer";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Testing your JS.Fiddle I was getting the same issue on IE. I found that if I changed the `font-size` from `em` to `px` the hover content displayed as expected. You can [see your update fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/q15Lw90d/18/).

I did a little research and found this quote on CSS-Tricks website and I believe the same concept is happening in your case.

> There are still a few obnoxious things with ems, like the cascading.
>   If you decide that list items should be font-size: 1.1em and then have
>   nested lists, it will cascade and grow the font size of the child
>   lists. You probably didn't want that. You can fix it with li li {
>   font-size: 1em; } but that's the kind of thing that can grind your
>   gourd. That's where rem's can come in, but that can be tricky as well
>   since there is less browser support (IE 9+).

All that to say you can change your font sizes to use something other than `em` and you should be good.

You can read a [similar question posted here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322916/ie9-bug-with-increased-font-size-of-css-content).