# font size displaying different on IE 11 than other browsers

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, fonts, font-size

I have a site I'm working on where I have some text that needs to view close to the same size on all browsers.  I'm using 1.6em as the font size in the pics below.  The problem is that in IE 11 the font appears way larger than in it does in Chrome/FF/Safari.  I have tried every font sizing option I can think of, such as; px,vh,vw,vmin,% but, all still render larger in IE 11 than all other browsers.  Does anyone know a good work-around for this?

Not sure if it makes a difference but I am using a google font instead of a regular font.

Sample in Chrome (this is how it should look)
[image]

Sample in IE 11 
[image]

My HTML:

```
<div class="banner-wrap">
     <div>
          <h1>Where Compassion Lives</h1>
     </div>
     <img class="banner" src="assets/images/banner_title_home.png">
     <img class="greg" src="assets/images/greg-transparent.png">
</div>
```

MY CSS:

```
.banner-wrap {
     position: relative;
     width: 100%;
     max-width: 796px;
     margin-top: 0px;
     margin-right: auto;
     margin-bottom: 0px;
     margin-left: auto;
}
.banner-wrap div {
     font-size: 1.6em;
     position: absolute;
     bottom: 59px;
     left: 0px;
     width: 100%;
     height: auto;
     z-index: 40;
     font-family: 'Kaushan Script', cursive;
     color: #FFF;
     letter-spacing: 0.2em;
     opacity: 0.9;
     text-align: center;
     text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #999;
}
.banner-wrap img.banner {
     position: absolute;
     bottom: 59px;
     left: 0px;
     width: 100%;
     height: auto;
     z-index: 30;
}
.banner-wrap img.greg {
     position: absolute;
     bottom: 30px;
     right: -50px;
     width: 19vmin;
     max-width:180px;
     height: auto;
     z-index: 40;
}
```

Comment: I think you might find your solution in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322916/ie9-bug-with-increased-font-size-of-css-content.  It suggests using rem instead of em.

Comment: Thank you...I have not heard of rem yet.  I did try it and unfortunately I am getting the exact same result....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind...figured it out.  since I was assigning the font-size using the selector div the user-agent style for the h1 tag was overriding my div font-size style.  Changed my font-size style to use the h1 selector and all is good.